# How to login in django with https/ssl at deploy server

Tags: python, django, nginx, https

I have django project. It works well on my Mac.But it's not work well on GCP(Ubuntu 17).

When I try login from login page. I cant login and authorize. I return same login page. No thing happen. Just reload same page.

This site uses Nginx with uWSGI
I'm thinking this problem comes from https/ssl settings.

If you know how to solve this problem, please let me know.

This is my code:
urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import  url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout_then_login
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'invo'
urlpatterns = [

    # Login Logout
    url(r'^login/$', login,
        {'template_name': 'invo/login.html'},
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout_then_login, name='logout'),

]
```

nginx setting

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}
# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/tekis.biz/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/tekis.biz/privkey.pem;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name tekis.biz; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;
    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste
    location /static {
        alias /home/teranori/invoice/invo/static/; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }
    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/teranori/invoice/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
        proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
from os.path import dirname, abspath

from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xxx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
# DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['tekis.biz','104.154.150.16', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'invo.apps.InvoConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'



# [START dbconfig]
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'xxx',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}





# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ja'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = BASE_DIR+'/invo/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'https://tekis.biz/static/'

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'invo/static/'),
)

# DJANGO_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
# PROJECT_ROOT = dirname(DJANGO_ROOT)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'invo.InvoUser'

# AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
#     'invo.backends.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend'
# ]
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

AUTH_USER_EMAIL_UNIQUE = True

# SILENCED: Username is not unique
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ["auth.W004"]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_URL = "/login/"


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(STATIC_URL, 'templates')],
        'DIRS': ['static/templates/'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                # 'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
                # 'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
    'ragendja.template.app_prefixed_loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
)

# HTPPS/SSL
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Comment: Have you created the user that you're trying to log in as on your deployment server?

Comment: Yes I did. Is there something what should I check?

Comment: Oh! my python manage.py createsuperuser .Has error! I should fix this error.